# How to connect azure web app to JSP repo (with uncompiled sources)?

Tags: java, azure, jsp

I have a github repo. It contains JSP files. No maven project, no prebuilt WAR. Just alike I would have cshtml pages. Is there any tutorial on how to make azure work with JSP sources?

Comment: Any updates now?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue , you need to deploy Java web project into Azure from GitHub.

You could refer to the [video](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/deploying-to-azure-from-github/) or the [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-github) about deployment.

Deploying Java web application on Azure WebApps is similar to deploying it into Tomcat or Jetty. You should deploy it into the directory `webapps`. on Azure WebApps, the `webapps` is at the path `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. You can find it thru the Debug console of  `Kudu` Tool at the url `https://<azure_webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

When you are deploying project from GitHub, the Azure will clone the files & directories of a branch of project repository from GitHub to the path `wwwroot` on Azure.

So the simple way to deploy from Github is push the `webapps/<java_app_name>` directory contains the files & directories of your Java web application archive into GitHub repository. Azure will help you pulling and deloping them.

Then you can browse the url `https://<azure_webapp_name>.azurewebsites.net/<java_app_name>/`.

Hope it helps you.